# how to prevent IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

this code will give max sum and min sum in a list
for input like 1 2 3 4 5 the output is coming properly like 14 10
when i enter these numbers 7 69 2 221 8974 error is coming like this
IndexError: list index out of range
i have tried below code

```
import math
lst = list(map(int,input().strip().split()))
lst1 = sorted(lst)
ls = []
for i in lst1:
    ls.append(math.fsum(lst1)-lst1[i-1])
print(round(min(ls), ),round(max(ls), ))
```

Comment: `for i in lst1` will iterate over items in list. `i` will be the items and not index number. So when you call using `1 2 3 4 5` all indices are present, but when you call `7 69 2 221 8974`, the index 7-1=6 is not there so it throws error there

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are iterating on lst1s values and in your loop, `i` will contains lists values (in your second example, it will be equal to 7 and then 69 and ...). you need to use indexes instead. try this one :

```
import math
lst = list(map(int,input().strip().split()))
lst1 = sorted(lst)
ls = []
for i,_ in enumerate(lst1):
    ls.append(math.fsum(lst1)-lst1[i])
print(round(min(ls), ),round(max(ls), ))
```

Comment: Correct, so upvoted your answer.  But would also point out you probably should use the built-in `sum` function rather than `math.fsum` since there's no need for the extra computational complexity of math.fsum for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly and foremost What is max sum and min sum in a list ?

Could you explain it better.

```
ls.append(math.fsum(lst1)-lst1[i-1])
```

if you alter this line, you won't get such error .